# Auto-Expand Kendo Grid on Load

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid

I'm using a Kendo Grid on my ASP.Net MVC Web Application, I want to auto expand the trees on Load. I've searched the internet but I couldn't find any solution.

> This is what my grid looked like on load:

[image: Auto-collapsed]

> I want it to auto-expand expand on load like this:

[image]

Is there any way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The expandRow method of the Grid accepts a single row or a collection of rows as a parameter, so you could pass all master rows.

```
dataBound: function() {
    this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row"));
}
```

This can be found in the documentation here [Link](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-expandRow)

Comment: is there any other alternatives? the expandrow makes my browser slow

Comment: Are you using in VS dev mode. How much data do you have, If you have allot of data you might want to try paging the data into chunks so it doesnt have to load everything at once

Comment: What version of Kendo are you using?

Comment: Also if you dont want to page, Maybe you can use scrollable->virtual, this would make it faster, Also check for frozen columns, I have seen that cause slowdowns.

Comment: @ChesterJohn Did you ever find a solution? The `expandRow()` call takes Chrome 25 seconds on my i7 w/16 GB ram. This isn't a solution for me to ship to customers.